# Why do my matrix dimensions not agree?

Tags: matlab

The file data5.mat contains x values and corresponding y values. I am trying to find the least squares line to plot alongside the x,y plot. The line is to be of the form
y=sin(a*x)*exp(b*x^c). I have this script

```
clear
load 'data5b.mat'
a=linspace(-50,50,100);
b=linspace(-50,50,100);
c=linspace(-50,50,100);
for i=1:length(a)
    for j=1:length(b)
        for k=1:length(c)
                Err(i,j,k) = sum((y-sin(a(i)*x)*exp(b(j)*x.^c(k))).^2);
        end  
    end
end
pcolor(Err)
```

yet, when I run the script, I receive:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in problem_4_hw4 (line 9)
            Err(i,j,k) = sum((y-sin(a(i)*x)*exp(b(j)*x.^c(k))).^2);
```

Comment: One of you multiplications doesn't work because the matrices don't have the correct dimension. Check the size of each matrix you are multiplying to locate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
Err(i,j,k) = sum((y-sin(a(i)*x).*exp(b(j)*x.^c(k))).^2);
```

sin() is a vector the same size as x, so is exp(), so you need `.*` between them

Comment: I added it, yet my programs is still very slow now:(

Comment: @ayshaw Maybe post a new question asking for speeding it up?